# Painting a line out of circles

Tags: java, line, paint

Im not having any type of syntax error, but more something on the mathematical/logic side. So Im trying to draw a line out of circles, giving only the start and the end point. My problem lies in getting the slope of the line. Here is my code for getting the slope and painting the line:

```
public void setVectorX(){
         xVector = difX/difY;
     }
     public void setVectorY(){
         yVector = difY/difX;
     }

     public void makeLine(){ 
         setVectorX();
         setVectorY();

         double prevX;
         double prevY;

         for(int i = 0; i < d; i++){

             if(i == 0){
                 prevX = startX;
                 prevY = startY;
             } else {
                 Circle prev = line.get(i-1);
                 prevX = prev.getX();
                 prevY = prev.getY();
             }

             Circle circ = new Circle(prevX+xVector,prevY+yVector,thickness,color);
             line.add(circ);
         }
     }
```

The problem with this is, the closer the end point gets to being on once of the same axis, there are larger spaces in between each of the circles, until no circles are actually painted. Does anyone know a more effective way to do this so the line paints how it should 100% of the time?

Thanks in advance!

Heres what it should look like:

[image]

Heres what it looks like as one of the axis at the end approaches the same axis as the start:

[image]

Here is the code for declaring d, difX, and difY as requested:

```
public Line(int nStartX, int nStartY, int nEndX, int nEndY, int nThickness,Color nColor){
         startX = nStartX;
         startY = nStartY;

         endX = nEndX;
         endY = nEndY;

         thickness = nThickness;

         d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((startX-endX), 2)+Math.pow((startX-endX), 2));

         color = nColor;

         difX = endX-startX;
         difY = endY-startY;

         makeLine();
     }
```

Comment: This maybe would be one of the rare occasions when adding some image would really help. You know, like showing a picture "this is how it looks right now".

Comment: We're missing too much code to actually find a solution. `xVector` `yVector` are not declared as int?

Comment: They are declared as double

Comment: difX and/or difY seem wrong. Failing to post a complete code sample doesn't help.

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the dots get more spaced as the difference between difX and difY becomes large. adding this method then calling it after setting the vectors should fix it.
here is the method:

```
public void rescale(){
    double hyp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xVector,2) + Math.pow(yVector,2));
    xVector /= hyp;
    yVector /= hyp;
}
```

now change:

```
setVectorX();
setVectorY();
```

to

```
setVectorX();
setVectorY();
rescale();
```

also, you should change

```
xVector = difX/difY;
```

to

```
xVector = difX
```

same for yVector

the second problem is you accidentally used difX twice. you did:

```
d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((startX-endX), 2)+Math.pow((startX-endX), 2));
```

when it should be:

```
d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((startX-endX), 2)+Math.pow((startY-endY), 2));
```

Comment: if you want all the code I used to test it look here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mKxaEBymIBRHCUJjeJZRTbtiBAuRyr2ifiCb-O8rY_o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you! This works almost perfectly, but there is a slight problem. The closer I get to being on the same axis, the short the line gets. I entered the points 1,150 for the end point and the line is extremely short. When the axis overlap, the entire line disappears. My for loop run on d(distance) maybe this is whats causing some problems?

Comment: difX and difY are the difference of X and the difference of Y, not the end points. I will change them to be the end points and see if this changes anything.

Comment: So I changed difX and difY to the endpoints, changed the distance to what you said, and now the line doesnt show up at all.

Comment: could you post the code of where you declare difX difY and d?

Comment: Its been posted

Comment: Thank you so much! It now works in every direction, even when they are on the same axis.